# Print Devexpress grid from a page?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I am doing a project on  asp.net

I use Devexpress gridview 9.1 .

I would like to print the **gridview only**  on a button click.
Basically **no other controls** in the page should be printed.

I found that, this is possible by passing the grid to next page and printing it there.
But my requirement doesn't allow that.

so is it possible to print the  **gridview alone on the same page** by any means??

Comment: If I understood you correctly, export to pdf/excel isn't acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Use the stanalone ASPxGridViewExporter component for this purpose:

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Exporting/Exporting.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void ASPxButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()){
                PrintableComponentLink pcl = new PrintableComponentLink(new PrintingSystem());
                pcl.Component = ASPxGridViewExporter1;
                pcl.Margins.Left = pcl.Margins.Right = 50;
                pcl.Landscape = true;
                pcl.CreateDocument(false);
                pcl.PrintingSystem.Document.AutoFitToPagesWidth = 1;
                pcl.ExportToPdf(ms);
                WriteResponse(this.Response, ms.ToArray(), System.Net.Mime.DispositionTypeNames.Inline.ToString());
            }
        }
        public static void WriteResponse(HttpResponse response, byte[] filearray, string type)
        {
            response.ClearContent();
            response.Buffer = true;
            response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
            response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            ContentDisposition contentDisposition = new ContentDisposition();
            contentDisposition.FileName = "test.pdf";
            contentDisposition.DispositionType = type;
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.ToString());
            response.BinaryWrite(filearray);
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            try
            {
                response.End();
            }
            catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
            {
            }

        }
```